# regex capture groups with optional group

Tags: regex, pandas

I'm trying to write a regex pattern capturing four different groups, the first groups ends either when we encounter either _ne or _re or a dot,
The second groups is an optional one, it captures the re or ne if encountered, otherwise it's empty, the third and fourth group are a bit easier to capture as they are just words proceeded by a dot.
here is a code snippet to get a sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.Series(
    ["abc_ne.c.d", "kc_E5_re.c.d", "kc_E5_re13.c.d", "kc_E5.c.d"]
).rename("raw")
```

using the following pattern `(\w+)(?:_(ne|re)\d*)\.(\w*)\.(\w*)` I can capture most cases

|  | raw | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc_ne.c.d | abc | ne | c | d |
| 1 | kc_E5_re.c.d | kc_E5 | re | c | d |
| 2 | kc_E5_re13.c.d | kc_E5 | re | c | d |
| 3 | kc_E5.c.d | nan | nan | nan | nan |

the exception is when the second group is absent, in which case it fails:
I tried making it optional `(\w+)(?:_(ne|re)\d*)?\\.(\w*)\.(\w*)`
but it captures everything in the first groups up to the dot.

|  | raw | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc_ne.c.d | abc_ne | nan | c | d |
| 1 | kc_E5_re.c.d | kc_E5_re | nan | c | d |
| 2 | kc_E5_re13.c.d | kc_E5_re13 | nan | c | d |
| 3 | kc_E5.c.d | kc_E5 | nan | c | d |

This snippet could be used to capture groups with pandas if needed:

```py
pattern = r'(\w+)(?:_(ne|re)\d*)?\.(\\w*)\.(\w*)'
sample.to_frame().join(sample.str.extract(pattern))
```

The expected output is:

|  | raw | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc_ne.c.d | abc | ne | c | d |
| 1 | kc_E5_re.c.d | kc_E5 | re | c | d |
| 2 | kc_E5_re13.c.d | kc_E5 | re | c | d |
| 3 | kc_E5.c.d | kc_E5 | nan | c | d |

Can anyone help me get the pattern right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which one is the expected output?

Comment: @mozway I added the expected output

Comment: Then @JvdV's answer is probably what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you probably want the 2nd group in an optional non-capture group and make the characters captured by the 1st group lazy:

```
^(\w+?)(?:_([nr]e\d*))?\.(\w+)\.(\w+)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrxJtX/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(\w+?)` - 1st Capture group to catch 1+ (Lazy) word-characters (thus including underscore);
- `(?:_([nr]e\d*))?` - Optional non-capture group to match an underscore and an nested 2nd capture group to match both 're' or 'ne' followed by 0+ digits;
- `\.(\w+)\.(\w+)` - Match both the 3rd and 4th capture group in succession inbetween literal dots;
- `$` - End-line anchor.